# How to do FILTER in (instead of FILTER is)

Tags: mdx

I have the following query:

```
Filter(
    [Team].[Hierarchy].[Code].members,
    [Team].[Hierarchy].currentmember.parent is [Team].[Hierarchy].[Division].[South]
)
```

How would I be able to check if the division is `South` or `North` (without doing two equivalent checks) is there something equivalent to:

```
Filter(
    [Team].[Hierarchy].[Code].members,
    [Team].[Hierarchy].currentmember.parent 
      IN {[Team].[Hierarchy].[Division].[South], [Team].[Hierarchy].[Division].[North]}
)
```

Current I am using this verbose approach because I'm not sure how to do the `in set` test:

```
Filter(
    [Team].[Hierarchy].[Code].members,
    [Team].[Hierarchy].currentmember.parent is [Team].[Hierarchy].[Division].[South]
 or [Team].[Hierarchy].currentmember.parent is [Team].[Hierarchy].[Division].[North]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Exists function like this :

```
 Exists(
        [Team].[Hierarchy].[Code].members,
        {[Team].[Hierarchy].[Division].[South], [Team].[Hierarchy].[Division].[North]}
       )
```